# Taking an input and rounding it up to the highest week.

Tags: python-3.x, rounding

new to Python or any programming languages, started learning a few weeks ago. Basically I need to figure out a code that will take a user input of number of days and translate it into weeks. Sounds easy enough, but say the user inputs 8 days, that would be considered two weeks. Any input must be rounded up to the nearest week.

So far I have

```
days = int(input("Please enter the number of days you will have the car: "))
weeks = (days/7)
```

but after that I am not sure how to make the code round the input up to the highest week.

Thanks for any help in advance!
Mezy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also use the modulus  operator

```
weeks = (days // 7 ) + (1 if days % 7 != 0 else 0)
```

Comment: `(days + 6) // 7` or `-(-days // 7)` are simpler, and don't require the modulus.